# Matlab - multiply matrix with vector of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix of scalars (A):

```
    1  2  3 
    4  5  6 
    7  8  9
```

And `3` other matrices of the same size (`100X200`), B,C,D.

I want to do the following:

`A*[B,C,D]` so that the outcome will be `[1*B + 2*C + 3*D, 4*B + 5*C + 6*D, 7*B + 8*C + 9*D]`.

Using normal multiplication `*` does not work since `[B,C,D]` obviously isn't of size `3X3`. How can it be done correctly?

Comment: The easiest, clearest, and most maintainable way to do this is to use loops and element-wise multiplication `.*`. There is a way to permute `A` into 4 dimensions and then sum, but it's very hard to visualize and if I actually write it, I wouldn't be able to remember in 2 weeks exactly what it does without working back through the steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What you want to do is this giant sparse matrix multiplication

  [image: fig]

  where **I** is the identity matrix, and the above are stacked vectors and matrix where all the rows and columns are appended together.
- What you should do as mentioned in the comments is to use the `.*` operator to write

  ```
  F = 1.*B + 2.*C + 3.*D
  G = 4.*B + 5.*C + 6.*D
  H = 7.*B + 8.*C + 9.*D
  ```